# Apache goes idle in Ubuntu 12.04 VM

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Mac Mini running Ubuntu Server 12.04 in a VM on VirtualBox, I have a basic LAMP setup going on. The VM is set to bridged and thus has it's own IP, if the VM is active I have no problem resolving my site externally using my domain name. I have the DNS records set to point to my external IP and my router is configured for port 80 on the VMs IP. The problem occurs when the VM goes "idle", the screen goes black and a key press wakes it up. When it goes idle my domain no longer resolves to my VM (I get redirected to my DNS host), but accessing the VM by it's internal IP works fine and appears to "wake" the VM up.

I'm not sure what's going on, either the VMs NIC is powering down and wakes on internal request, Ubuntu is going "idle", my domain isn't waiting long enough for a response or Apache2 isn't configured correctly. The KeepAlive variable is set to ON in apache2.conf.

Any help regarding this would be awesome.

Comment: I think this may be more appropriate for [server fault](http://serverfault.com/), but I may be wrong.